# how can I make an a tag with a routerLink force a reload of that route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I have routes defined like:

```js
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
  },
  {
    path ':id',
    component: MyComponent,
  },
  ...
```

So I can go to `/foo` or `/foo/123`

The component knows to fetch that specific id or to fetch a collection of all records whether or not the id parameter exists..

The problem is, I have a link that does:

```html
<a routerLink="/foo">foo!</a>
```

If I type into the url bar `/foo` I see the list of records, and if I type `/foo/123` it also works correctly and loads that specific record.  However, if I am on `/foo/123` and then click that link I see the url change to `/foo` but it does nothing, does not re-render the component, so the it is still showing the 123 record, rather than the list of records as it should...

How can I force it to do a reload?

I tried putting `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` in the route, I also tried `{onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’}` on the app level forRoot route config options, and also tried the incredibly dumb hack I've seen multiple people talk about with adding a queryParam of a timestamp on the `<a>` tag...  None of those things worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by subscribing to the **route params**, and whenever it emits the new value, you can re-initialize your component data.

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

...

private subs: Subscription[] = [];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subs.push(
    this.route.params.subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        const id = response['id'];
        this.initializeData();
      },
      error: (errorResponse) => {
        console.log('ERROR: ', errorResponse);
      },
    })
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subs.forEach((s) => s?.unsubscribe());
}

initializeData() {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: man... this seems soooooo ridiculous!

Comment: This is actually one common practice. Why do you think it's not proper?

Comment: because it's a hack.  I want angular to tear down the component (call ngDestroy) and re-create it.

Comment: It's not a hack, it's pure Angular... and it solves your use case :D